# iPhone 6S audio issue while streaming

Tags: ios, iphone, audio-recording, sample-rate

I developed an iOS application with live video streaming. I fixed the audio sample rate to 8k. Audio works fine up to iPhone6 devices, but when i stream video in 6s and 6s plus audio part is not working. How can i fixed this issue? I tried in different blogs and found that in iPhone 6s sample rate is locked in 48k. How can i manually down sample? Because the library that i used for live streaming works only in 8k. Please help me on these

Comment: Do we able to set 'preferSampleRate'? Did you try it? BTW, where did you find that iPhone 6s sample rate is locked in 48k?

Comment: Please look on this.. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20677

Comment: Also please look on this, https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/20187

Comment: Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do your own sample rate conversion by low-pass filtering the data to a frequency below 4 kHz, and then taking every 6th sample (to convert 48 ksps samples to 8 ksps samples).